# Binding enabled also when minimized Tcl/Tk

Tags: events, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit, toplevel

I'm looking for a way to make key binding always active even when the top level is minimized. In other words, when the Wish app is in the background.
I work in Windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on windows, get the TWAPI package (Tcl Windows API) and use `twapi::register_hotkey`.  Documentation is at http://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.0/input.html#register_hotkey and there's a blog article on this at http://www.magicsplat.com/blog/hotkeys-on-demand/ .

Answer (score 0):

Tk is not designed to work that way. You'll need something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) instead.